# Issues with python 3 and relative imports

Tags: python, relative-import

I have a layout like this:

```
src
   __init__.py
   main.py
   examples
      __init__.py
      example_project.py
   library
      __init__.py
      some_library_code.py
```

`example_project.py` uses code from `some_library_code.py`
I run the `example_project.py` like that:
`***\src>: python examples\example_project.py` and get `ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package`
I've read through some answers on SO and found that I need some construction
`sys.path.append(os.path.normpath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)), os.pardir)))`
to be present in `example_project.py`

My `example_project.py` import section looks like that:

```
import os, sys
sys.path.append(os.path.normpath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)), os.pardir)))

from ..library import some_library_code
```

but that doesn't work and shows the same `ImportError`

**UPD**:
if I change `from ..library *****` to `from library *****` then it works but the IDE doesn't recognize imported types and shows error around `import` clause

Comment: "ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package" Ordinarily, your "parent package" would be the `src` folder. Did you try running the program from outside of that?

Comment: yes, i run `example_project` which is in `examples` package from `src` directory. And this project uses `src/library` package

Comment: @karlknechtel but even if i run the code from within `src/examples` directory it still throws the same error

Comment: No, I'm saying you should back outside of `src` entirely.

Answer (score 1):

Revert the sys path hacks and instead run your code as:

```
***\src>: python -m examples.example_project
```

This way tells python to run the *module* `example_project` that lives in the *package* `examples`. Otherwise python has no way (when you run the script directly that is) to know that this script is part of a package - hence the error. The syspath hacks will fail in subtle ways (the IDE can't really follow those dynamic sys path additions - there are settings for this but then starts to become complicated, hence hack - but there are worst consequences even undefined behavior) while running your script with the -m switch *from the parent dir of your root package* is the recommended way of running scripts.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add `__init__.py` in `library` folder. Here is the documentation https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#regular-packages

Comment: I'm sorry, i've updated the layout in question. I already had these files

Answer (score 0):

Try from `library.some_library_code import Something`.

Comment: I'm sorry, i've updated the layout in question. I already had these files